# Why Interrupts not generates by C code but easy generates by assembly instructions?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, interrupt-handling, osdev

I am programming a little kernel, and implement idt and interrupts.

This C code in my little kernel not generate any interrupt:

```
int x = 5/0;

int f[4];
f[5] = 8;
```

But this Assembly code can generate any interrupt:

```
asm("int $0");
```

(and handlers work right).

Help me to understand why this situation can happens.

I also tried this:

```
    int a = 3;
    int b = 3;  
    int c = a-b;
    int x = a/c;
```

Nothing I try in c code can generate exception for me.

Even this not worked:

```
int div_by_0(int a, int b){return a/b;}

int x = div_by_0(5, 0);
```

Comment: `int $0` is triggering an interrupt in your computer’s kernel via the operating system. And because C has no boundary checking, you will need to look elsewhere. You could use `asm()` to create an interrupt in assembly though.

Comment: As any decent book, tutorial or class should have mentioned, C doesn't have any bounds-checking. If you index an array out of bounds it leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which *could* lead to a crash (but not an "interrupt" the way you can in assembly).

Comment: but as i understand x =5/0 C must generate division by zero interurpt exception at least.

Comment: The `idiv` instruction would generate the interrupt, however the compiler is not obliged to use it and typically will not use it for division by a constant (especially zero). If you hide the fact that you're dividing by zero from the compiler, then it may work.

Comment: For the division, try using variables whose values are set at run-time instead of constant literals. And *use* the result to make sure the compiler doesn't optimize it away. Also note you can get different *exceptions* (the common term for such "interrupts") for integer and floating point division by zero.

Comment: If you just want to test your kernels exception handling, then perhaps write small assembly functions that perform these operations instead?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Interestingly, on GCC 10.1 x86-64, `-O3`, the compiler generates an undefined opcode. ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/j54Q1R))

Comment: Divide by 0 don't trigger a fault on every platform. ARM Cortex-m doesn't not generate any fault by default (must be enabled) otherwise the division just return 0. And check assembly for compiler optimization when you make these tries.

Comment: Read [this blog about undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html)

Comment: @ThomasJager Heh, well that's UB in action! :)

Comment: `but as i understand x =5/0 C must generate division by zero interurpt exception at least` No: it is an initialiser, not an assignment. Initialisers are evaluated at compile time.

Comment: The error, division by zero, is surely detected by the compiler in optimization phase, **because is constant**, simply rising the signal for division by zero exception, without invoking the interrupt. About the assembler instruction, you're using a **software interrupt** instruction, the compiler can't optimize it out, the instruction invokes the interrupt. Try `int div_by_0(int a, int b){return a/b;}`, then call it with 5 and 0 as parameters.

Comment: Hey in your `int x = 5/0;` the division by 0 is made by the preprocessor! It will never reach the compiler... I suggest to look at the generated assembly code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void fun ( void )
{
    int a = 3;
    int b = 3;
    int c = a-b;
    int x = a/c;
}

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <fun>:
   0:   f3 c3                   repz retq
```

there is no divide to trigger a divide by zero.  It is all dead code.

And none of this has anything to do with the int instruction, these are completely separate topics.

As mentioned in the comments test it without using dead code.

```
int fun0 ( int x )
{
    return(5/x);
}
int fun1 ( void )
{
    return(fun0(0));
}
```

but understand that it still may not have the desired effect:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <fun0>:
   0:   b8 05 00 00 00          mov    $0x5,%eax
   5:   99                      cltd   
   6:   f7 ff                   idiv   %edi
   8:   c3                      retq   
   9:   0f 1f 80 00 00 00 00    nopl   0x0(%rax)

0000000000000010 <fun1>:
  10:   0f 0b                   ud2
```

because the optimizer for fun1 could see the fun0 function.  You want to have the code under test in a separate optimization domain.  In this case above then the idiv would generate the divide by zero.  And then it is becomes an operating system issue as to how that is handled and if it is visible to you.

Comment: `volatile` my friend.

Comment: @Joshua   volatile creates other issues, leaves a bad taste, once in a blue moon starts an argument on SO.  Certainly include it in your answer though.

Comment: point being is the OP is probably not generating a divide instruction thus no divide by zero.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are seeing is because division by 0 is undefined behaviour in *C/C++*. The compiler has managed to do enough optimization at compile time to realize you are dividing by zero. The compiler is free to do anything from things like halting and catching fire to making the result 0. Some compilers will emit a `ud2` instruction to raise a CPU exception. The result is undefined.

You have a couple of options. Write your division in assembly and call that function from *C/C++*. Since you are using GCC (works for CLANG as well) You can also use inline assembly to generate a division by zero with something like:

```
#include <stdint.h>  /* or replace uint16_t with unsigned short int */ 

void div_by_0 (void)
{
    asm ("div %b0" :: "a"((uint16_t)0));
    return;
}
```

This sets *AX* to 0 then divides *AX* by *AL* with the `DIV` instruction. 0/0 is undefined and will raise a Division Exception (#DE). This inline assembly should work with 16, 32, and 64-bit code.

---

In protected mode or long mode using `int $#` (Where `#` is the vector number) to trigger an exception is not always the same as getting a CPU generated exception. [Some exceptions](https://wiki.osdev.org/Exceptions) generated by the CPU push an error code on the stack after the return address that needs to be cleaned up by an interrupt handler. If you were to use `int $0x0d` from ring 0 to cause a #GP exception the interrupt handler would likely fault as it returns from the interrupt because using `int` to generate an exception never places an error code on the stack. This isn't a problem with `int $0` because #DE doesn't have an error code placed on the stack by the CPU.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be due to optimization flags. Due to a bit of confusion at Makefiles, the -O2 flag worked. If you enable the -O0 flag, exceptions work directly from C. And even this simple code throws an exceptions:

```
int x = 5/0;
```